# running task synchronously in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Plugin in MS Dynamics CRM 2011 which gets called on any new fixture creation. I want a task to run asynchronously when this plugin is called.

This will create around 40000 new rows in a table and is a long query which takes about 10 minutes to complete. I don't want Admin/User to wait while it completes creating all the records, I would rather let it running asynchronously and let user do other stuff.

Any help or sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking this outside of CRM into a separate process, e.g. scheduled console application, which periodically queries CRM for a particular situation and then creates the required records.

As a side, if your plugin is registered inside the sandbox, if it runs for more than 2 minutes CRM will stop it.

[Event Execution Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx#bkmk_Architecture)

> Regardless of whether a plug-in executes synchronously or
>   asynchronously, **there is a 2-minute time limit imposed on the
>   execution of a plug-in registered in the sandbox**. If the execution of
>   your plug-in logic exceeds the time limit, a System.TimeoutException
>   is thrown. If a plug-in needs more processing time than the 2-minute
>   time limit, consider using a workflow or other background process to
>   accomplish the intended task.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Async Plugin to achieve your goal.

Comment: I have added a step to my plugin i.e. Run in Context=Create, Pipe-line stage=Post-Operation and in my plugin class i have following code..
            base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(40, "Create", "", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(PostFixtureSeriesAssociateExecute)));
my PostFixtureSeriesAssociateExecute has all database functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried using plugin for this purpose and it did not work for several reasons and one of them was time out issue.

Finally I manage to make this work by using custom Workflow Activity which gets fired on insert into my entity.

This works perfect and runs async for (30-45min) depending on data.

Thanks for all suggestions